# What kind of Javascript function is this?

Tags: javascript, function, position, call

Exactly what kind of Javascript function is this, and how exactly do I use it?

```
position = this[this.options.position]();
```

I've looked up .call(), but there's hardly anything related to this strange use of Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `call`. What exactly do you not understand about this function call? This is just a property access yielding a function that is being called.

Comment: if `this.options.position` was `'left'` then it's `position = this.left();`

Answer (score 3):

It's not a *function*, it's a function *call*. That expression looks up the property named by `this.options.position` on the object referenced by `this` and then calls the function that property's value refers to. So for instance, if `this.options.position` contains the string `"one"`, then it's like doing `position = this.one()`.

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  options: {},
  one: function() {
    console.log("This is function one");
    return 1;
  },
  two: function() {
    console.log("This is function two");
    return 2;
  },
  example: function() {
    var position = this[this.options.position]();
    console.log(position);
  }
}

obj.options.position = "one";
obj.example();

obj.options.position = "two";
obj.example();
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with functions, but with [*property access*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). This one is called [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation). It allows you to access a property whose name is determined at runtime.

For example, these two are equivalent:

```
this.left() // dot notation

//

var position = 'left';
this[position](); // bracket notation
```

---

If you have worked with arrays, then you have come across bracket notation already:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr[0]);
```